# Usign pandas python, How do I make groupby of a subset of a groupby not return filtered off values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

So I'm using Plotly to plot some grouped data. The problem is that after I updated pandas, my code stopped working. I managed to isolate what was going wrong. It turns out that inside px.bar, there is a get_group that returns groups which I filtered out. Why is that? How could I resolve this?

```
# Code outside px.bar
old_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                       'id1': [18, 22, 19, 14, 14, 11, 20, 28],
                       'id2': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4],
                       'id3': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 7, 9, 12]})


new_df = old_df2.groupby([pd.Categorical(old_df2.name),'id2'])['id3'].count().fillna(0)
    
# Transforms count from series to data frame
new_df = new_df.to_frame()

# rowname to index 
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

new_df = new_df[new_df["level_0"].isin(["A","B"])]

# Take this bit as an example of what happens inside px.bar
new_df.groupby("level_0").count()

# Result
#          id2  id3
# level_0          
# A          5    5
# B          5    5
# C          0    0


# Desired Result
#          id2  id3
# level_0          
# A          5    5
# B          5    5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me again. I solved the problem. This was done by unlinking the objects ( don't know if this is a thing, but apparently it is). for this, I created a dict from the data frame and a data frame from the dict. It's not pretty, but it works. I transformed new_df into a dict with

```
new_df_list = new_df.to_dict("records")

unlinked_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df_list )
```